# How to modify the array inside foreach to process more elements without another loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, batch-processing

Basically, what I'm trying to do could be narrowed down to:

```
$itemsToProcess = array(1,2,3);

foreach ($itemsToProcess as $item) {
    if ($item == 2) {
        // processing of item 2 produces 2 new items that should be processed:
        $itemsToProcess[] = 7;
        $itemsToProcess[] = 8;
        continue;
    }
    echo $item;
}
```

which I'd like to output `1378` in one sequence, without doing this:

```
$itemsToProcess = array(1,2,3);
$newItemsToProcess = array();

foreach ($itemsToProcess as $item) {
    if ($item == 2) {
        $newItemsToProcess[] = 7;
        $newItemsToProcess[] = 8;
        continue;
    }
    echo $item;
}

foreach ($newItemsToProcess as $newItem) {
    echo $newItem;
}
```

Note: Processing of elements `7` and `8` will not yield more items to process (i.e. those 2 loops would suffice indeed), I just don't like it when code **repeats** so maybe there's some **clean solution** for this.

I'm quite familiar with PHP, yet I don't really know how some constructs of the language are implemented and what happens "behind the scene".

Comment: your sample is pretty basic. Why not just say `if($item != 2) echo $item;` - I'm sure your have a reason

Comment: You can create a recursive function where you submit your array, starting element and all the logic.

Comment: I've the same question that Kai Qing

Comment: I think he want to add elements to array and reflect its addition

Comment: @andrew - never the less, still a simple conditional within the original loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the input array in a foreach loop, but replacing foreach with `while`, `list` and `each`, you can get a similarly simple solution that does what you wanted.

```
$itemsToProcess = array(1,2,3);
while(list(, $val) = each($itemsToProcess)) {
    if($val == 2) {
        $itemsToProcess[] = 7;
        $itemsToProcess[] = 8;
        continue;
    }
    echo $val;

}
```

Comment: Since php4 no one uses list+each to iterate over a php array, thats bad code style.

Comment: +1 Since the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) itself shows the possible usage of `each` for this purpose. Although it might be a bit slower than `foreach` (up to few miliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

The last foreach could be realized by simply using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$items = [1, 3, 7, 8];
var_dump(implode($items));
```

To avoid iteration overall you could use:

```
$items = [1, 2, 3];

$key = array_search(2, $items);
if ($key !== false) {
    unset($items[$key]);
    $items = array_merge($items, [7, 8]); 
}

var_dump(implode($items));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values by reference, then the newly added items will be processed in the same foreach:

```
foreach ($itemsToProcess as &$item) {
    ....
    $itemsToProcess[] = $item;
}
unset($value); // always unset the reference
```

This works because of a side effect of using elements as a reference. When the `foreach` is invoked normally, a copy of the array is made, and the copy is iterated over. When you ask `foreach` to give you the reference, this copy is never made (as you're telling `foreach` that you want to work with the array itself). It's an undocumented side effect that relies on the internal implementation of `foreach` in the current VM, and I'd try to avoid that. [[reference]](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

http://ideone.com/CNbYGf

Comment: you may want to expand this answer. I get it, but if OP is asking this question at all he may not be too adept at php yet. The &$item in this case might not explain everything

Comment: LOL. How the fact that `$item` is initialized as a reference affects the way the `foreach` iterates through elements?

Comment: This seems to be hack rather than appropriate solution. I know what `foreach` that initializes value as reference does and the documentation that you are refering to states *"As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior"*

Comment: Alright, I think you need to create some other example, more appropriate to what you really want then

Comment: @1nflktd: No, you've got it right. I just want to know what makes you write this: *"If you want to add itens to the array you are processing, pass the values by reference, then they will be processed in the same `foreach`."* ?

Comment: @LihO I think this answer does pretty much everything you're asking for.  It's the most elegant solution by a mile

Comment: The reason it works is because of a side effect of using elements as a reference. When the foreach() is invoked normally, a copy of the array is made, and the copy is iterated over. When you ask foreach to give you the reference, this copy is never made (as you're telling foreach that you want to work with the array itself). It's an undocumented side effect that relies on the internal implementation of foreach in the current VM, and I'd try to avoid that.

Comment: @LihO The php.net article 1nflktd linked to explains it pretty well

Comment: I dont see any reason why working with a reference is more elegant? Its hard to read and php internally keeps an reference of its stuff until you modify it. There are tons of articles about why explicit references in php are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `foreach` loop when it's not suitable. This is a good case for a while loop, where you use it as a queue.

```
while($item = array_shift($itemsToProcess))
{
    if ($item == 2)
    {
        $itemsToProcess[] = 7;
        $itemsToProcess[] = 8;
        continue;
    }

    echo $item;
}
```

That way you'll have a list of items that still needs processing while you run through the loop, you'll avoid a queue that grows bigger and bigger if there are lots of items to process and it code is simple (only one active line - nothing more to keep track of or handle).

Comment: This is nice solution, this code looks clean indeed, however if the `$itemsToPRocess` is large array, I think this will keep on changing all keys in this array at every iteration and it will be slow.

Comment: If that's an issue (and it might be, if you have an array in the 100k+ size), you might switch to using array_pop instead, and using it as a stack. That would change the order of traversal, but depending on the actual use case (instead of echoing numbers) that might not be a problem.